# inviting someone to dinner (in cantonese)

Tags: cantonese, nuance

I recently came across this statement to invite someone to dinner.

你介唔介意今晚同我食飯.

As this is my first time learning cantonese, I wanted to know what the nuance of 介意 is? Are there alternative statements in inviting someone to dinner?

In my mind, I would have said: 今晚不如同我食飯? Is this too aggressive and headstrong?

Thanks for your insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Normally `介唔介意` is used in situations where you expect your action may cause *mild displease* to the listener.

   In the context of an invitation, you may cause mild displease to someone unfamiliar if they do not wish to dine with you. Conversely, you would not expect a good friend of yours to react negatively to your invitation, so `介唔介意` will sound awkward. `介唔介意` is a fairly polite way of invitation for new acquaintances / strangers.

   However, in the following example, it can also be applied to people dear to you as well, for the simple fact that we cannot always read others' minds:

   > 你介唔介意我開冷氣呀？我有啲熱。
   >
   > Do you mind if I turn on the air conditioner? I'm feeling a bit hot.
2. Possible alternatives to `介唔介意` of similar extent of politeness are: `想唔想`, `肯唔肯` (somewhat blunt), `願唔願意`, `會唔會(想)` etc. You can even use the expression `唔知+sentence+呢？` as well for invitations, as in `唔知你願唔願意同我食飯呢？`.
3. Usually you expect an affirmative answer when using `不如` and `一於`. You can soften the headstrong-ness by adding sentence final particles like `～囉 lo3` and `～啦 laa1`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am intrigued by this: 唔知你願唔願意同我食飯呢？It is longer than the rest. In what situations would this be useful?

Comment: A courteous (perhaps a bit too courteous; somewhat old-fashioned) way of inviting new acquaintances to dinner. Less awkward than 介唔介意 to me (介唔介意 can at times be somewhat self-deprecating; or sarcastic when you want to mock others as being arrogant).

Answer (score 2):

介意 =  'mind' (v),

When you ask someone "你介唔介意 (do you mind) doing something", you are suggesting this something might inconvenience, trouble,  or displease him or her.

"你介唔介意今晚同我食飯?" = "Do you mind having dinner with me tonight?"

It sounds less asserted. Implies having dinner with you is doing you a favor.

> "今晚不如同我食飯" = "It is better to have dinner with me tonight"

It is not a proper sentence structure for requesting

You can use a requesting phrase like "好唔好" as in "今晚同我食飯好唔好?" to make it a proper request

Another way to make "今晚不如同我食飯" a request is to use a final particle.

Different final particle expresses different tone, emotion or meaning

Example:

"今晚不如同我食飯**吖**" -- 吖 (suggesting/ casual/ inviting)

"今晚不如同我食飯**啦**" -- 啦 (casual/ suggesting/ asserted)

There are many other ways to make an invitation. For example, '今晚一齊食飯好唔好?' or  '今晚一齊食飯啦'